# ursina FirstPersonController как извлечь скорость и позицию камеры

Tags: python-3.x, ursina

итак я пишу 3д игру на урсине и ни как не найду как мне в FirstPersonController извлечь скорость и позицию камеры и сохранить это в переменные и обращяйтесь ко мне на ты заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

возможно так можно получить скорость:

```
FirstPersonController.speed
```

или

```
my_speed = FirstPersonController.speed
```

с камерой всё похоже